# Find Overlapping Times in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am writing a query to detect overlapping times. It is for a room reservation system that should not make a reservation if the time slot user entered overlaps with any of the timeIn's and timeOut's stored already. I have my table structured as:

```
ID      BOARDROOM_TYPE  REQUEST_TIME            USER_REQUEST    SUBJECT                  FROM_DATE  TO_DATE     FROM_TIME               TO_TIME
17174   Board Room      06/11/2014 1:21:00 AM   User A          Some Subject             11/11/2014 11/11/2014  01/11/2014 2:30:00 PM   01/11/2014 5:00:00 PM
17172   Board Room      06/11/2014 12:50:58 AM  User B          Meeting                  11/11/2014 11/11/2014  01/11/2014 9:00:00 AM   01/11/2014 1:00:00 PM
```

Now according to this data, the room is reserved from 9 AM to 1 PM and then from 2:30 PM to 5 PM.

My Query for checking overlapping meeting times on the same date in the same room is:

```
select count(*) from meeting_data where not (to_time <= to_date('13:00','hh24:mi:ss') and from_time >= to_date('14:00','hh24:mi:ss')) and trunc(from_date) = trunc(Sysdate) and boardroom_type = 'Board Room' and deleted = 'N'
```

When timeIn = 13:00 and timeOut = 14:00, it returns 2 and if `count > 0`, then it should not insert data. It is working fine till this point.

The problem lies when I input overlapping times, like `timeIn = 09:00 timeOut = 14:00`, it still gives 2 and since `count > 0` it inserts even though there's already a reservation made in this time slot (ID = 17172).

What am i doing wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) from meeting_data 
where NOT (
      to_date(to_char(to_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '13:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi')
      not between from_time and to_time
  and to_date(to_char(to_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '14:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi')
      not between from_time and to_time
  and to_time not between to_date(to_char(to_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '13:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi')
                      and to_date(to_char(to_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '14:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi')  
  )
  and from_date between trunc(Sysdate) and trunc(Sysdate+1) -1/24/60/60 
  and boardroom_type = 'Board Room' and deleted = 'N';
```

The first three conditions check if there is no intersections with any [from_date, to_date] + check that [from_date, to_date] is not inside the desired interval

Also there was a problem in your query:

```
The default date values are determined as follows:
- The year is the current year, as returned by SYSDATE.
- The month is the current month, as returned by SYSDATE.
- The day is 01 (the first day of the month).
- The hour, minute, and second are all 0.
```

So `to_time <= to_date('13:00','hh24:mi:ss')` could give you undesired results depending on what date you're performing this comparision.

And minor change with `trunc(from_date) = trunc(Sysdate)` I removed a function on the column (which is a good candidate to be indexed)

If the intervals [09:00 - 13:00] and [13:00 - 14:00] are considered as not intersected then you may use not strict comparision:

Change

```
some_date not between from_time and to_time
```

To

```
some_date <= from_time or some_date >= to_time
```

Here is the modified query:

```
select count(*) from meeting_data 
where (to_date(to_char(from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') || '13:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi') > from_date
       and to_date(to_char(from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') || '13:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi') < to_date
   or to_date(to_char(from_date, 'YYYYMMDD') || '14:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi') > from_date
      and to_date(to_char(to_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '14:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi') < to_date
   or to_time > to_date(to_char(to_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '13:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi')
      and to_time < to_date(to_char(to_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '14:00','YYYYMMDDhh24:mi')
      )            
  and from_date between trunc(Sysdate) and trunc(Sysdate+1) -1/24/60/60 
  and boardroom_type = 'Board Room' and deleted = 'N';
```

Comment: still gives 2 on both the output. I want it to give number of rows overlapping and if these are > 0, it shouldn't insert proposed input. The query you suggested gives non zero on overlapping and non-overlapping slots both.

Comment: @Ingila Ejaz I added NOT, now the query should return count > 0 if there are some intersections (but it doesn't give the number of intersections)

Comment: again the same results. According to this data, the room is reserved from 9 to 1, then from 2:30 to 5. SO it should accpet meeting from 1 to 2 i.e 13 to 14. But providing 13 and 14 as timeIn and timeOut to this query, it gives 1 rather it should give 0 since it is empty slot.

Comment: @Ingila Ejaz Formally there is an intersection because 1 intersects with 13. If you allow these intersections then you can just use strict comparision

Comment: @Ingila Ejaz By the way in your query you used not strict comparision

Comment: But the previous meeting is to end at 1 and then from 1 to 2 the slot will be empty. If you see in my query in the question, I used <= and >= so it is not that strict comparison is what I require. Can you edit your answer to allow this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64682/discussion-between-ingila-ejaz-and-multisync).

Comment: Yes I used not strict comparison but it was giving same results in both overlapping and non overlapping inputs. That's what the question was all about.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question you need to check the user entered values with the database. So i think stored procedure is the way to go here. You can pass user entered values to the SP and check time is overlapping.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_date_clash (
  p_start_date IN DATE,
  p_end_date   IN DATE,
  l_count      OUT NUMBER
)
AS

BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   l_count
  FROM   meeting_data
  WHERE  from_time <= p_end_date
  AND    to_time   >= p_start_date
  AND    trunc(from_date) = trunc(Sysdate) 
  AND    boardroom_type = 'Board Room'
  AND    deleted = 'N';

END check_date_clash;
/
```

This will get count of overlapping records with the user entered period and return the count.

Comment: can you please tell me the code to execute this procedure everytime before a row is inserted? Like a beforeInsert Trigger?

Comment: Before Insert trigger will not prevent the inserting record. From where are you going to execute insertion? Is it from the source code or another procedure? You can call this procedure before inserting the record and according to return count you can decide whether to insert or not.

Comment: I just simply need to call this procedure with PHP and save the l_count in some variable. How do I do that? I'm getting Not a valid month error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a cross join, it will get records which are in between the existing timeline.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM MEETING_DATA A, MEETING_DATA B WHERE A.FROM_TIME > B.FROM_TIME AND A.FROM_TIME < B.TO_TIME AND ...;
```